# RobotFramework Selenium can't open chrome: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm unable to open headless chrome instance for automated tests. I get this error that the instance is crashing:

```
Parent suite setup failed:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5581a507ac93 <unknown>
#1 0x5581a4d5e186 <unknown>
#2 0x5581a4d929ae <unknown>
#3 0x5581a4d8ea4d <unknown>
#4 0x5581a4dd81ec <unknown>
#5 0x5581a4dcb8a3 <unknown>
#6 0x5581a4d9c693 <unknown>
#7 0x5581a4d9d09e <unknown>
#8 0x5581a503f0cb <unknown>
#9 0x5581a5043005 <unknown>
#10 0x5581a502b351 <unknown>
#11 0x5581a5043b97 <unknown>
#12 0x5581a500edef <unknown>
#13 0x5581a5068fd8 <unknown>
#14 0x5581a50691a2 <unknown>
#15 0x5581a5079e24 <unknown>
#16 0x7fea5922f044 <unknown>
```

I'm using:
robotframework: 6.1.1

robotframework-seleniumlibrary: 6.2.0

selenium: 4.16.0

Chrome: Google Chrome for Testing 122.0.6248.0

Chromedriver: ChromeDriver 122.0.6248.0

In Robot I specified those launch parameters:

```
--remote-debugging-port=9222 --start-maximized --headless=new --window-size=1920,1080 --disable-gpu --disable-extensions --disable-infobars --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS=true --setAcceptInsecureCerts=true --ignore-certificate-errors
```

When I try to launch Chrome via console with those parameters, it doesn't crash:

```
chrome --start-maximized --headless=new --window-size=1920,1080 --disable-gpu --disable-extensions --disable-infobars --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS=true --setAcceptInsecureCerts=true --ignore-certificate-errors
[24321:24335:0116/080212.967450:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24340:0116/080212.975474:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24340:0116/080212.975556:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24335:0116/080212.978862:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24321:24335:0116/080212.979139:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24321:24335:0116/080212.979174:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24321:24335:0116/080212.979188:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24321:24321:0116/080212.983166:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(157)] :components/enterprise/browser/controller/chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(161) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled. Please use the `--enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management` command line flag to enable it if you are not using the official Google Chrome build.
[24321:24335:0116/080212.995549:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[24321:24335:0116/080212.995596:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/9792b9ed-5023-4b1e-9179-107d90938498
[24321:24430:0116/080213.122854:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24430:0116/080213.122956:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24430:0116/080213.123067:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24430:0116/080213.123130:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[24321:24430:0116/080213.123185:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

I tried many combinations of launch parameters. I also tried to downgrade chrome and chromedriver but it didn't work.

I know that this issue is similar to many already here, but I already implemented all the comments I found, like using --headless and --no-sandbox, but those don't work. Many of those questions are for old/ancient versions of Chrome and Chromedriver and may not be applicable anymore.